# Kotlin / Native Installation Error : 'jni.h' file not found

Tags: java, c, gradle, kotlin

I have openjdk-9-jdk and jre installed.

I have added folders containing JDK C lib files in Compiler args:

```
cCompiler.args "-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/include"
cCompiler.args "-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/include/linux"
```

in gradle files:

```
kotlin-native-master/Interop/Indexer/build.gradle
and
kotlin-native-master/Interop/Runtime/build.gradle
```

**Full Error that I'm getting:**

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error:
>   /tmp/tmp17962303058800124468.c:2:10: fatal error: 'jni.h' file not
>   found

Why is it showing this error?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I fixed this problem. Do this:

1) Open:

> /home/kshitij/kotlin-native-master/Interop/StubGenerator/src/main/kotlin/org/jetbrains/kotlin/native/interop/gen/jvm/StubGenerator.kt

2) Go to line 919 and comment: `"-I$javaHome/../include/$it"`

3) Now add this, just below the above commented line:

```
"-I/usr/lib/jvm/java-9-openjdk-amd64/include/$it"
```

- Please add your java include path here. Don't copy paste exactly as above.

4) Save the file and run again. It should work now.